# Hippo CMS: channel manager does not work, preview website in composer mode does not work

Tags: java, maven, hippocms

I am using **hippo 11** and **maven server 3.3.9**, I deploy my website but when working on channel manager to preview website and open it in composer mode it does not work and still loading forever

And this

```
/site/_rp/cafebabe-cafe-babe-cafe-babecafebabe./channels/alfozan-preview
```

has this error:

```
failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
```

Comment: Are you running it on your local machine or are you deploying it to an application? Usually when you get a 500 error you will also get a message in your log file. What does it say?

Comment: Do you still experience the issue? Even with an incognito window? There is an old thread on the hippo community mailing list for a similar issue https://groups.google.com/d/topic/hippo-community/5XGsPrW8UjM/discussion but it refers an older hippo version and it doesn't clearly target the issue.